# Entity Framework 5 add entity and child entities with other foreign key relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework (EF) 5 Code First.

I've a self-referencing object, let's call it `Demo`:

```
public class Demo
{
    public int Id; 
    public string Name;
    public Demo Parent;
    public ICollection<Demo> Children;

    public Item Item;
}
```

This has a reference to another object, `Item`:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public Item Parent;
    public ICollection<Item> Children;
}
```

Yes, it's also self-referencing but this shouldn't matter. The database now has a foreign key based on an `Item_Id` that was added to the `Demo` table by the database migration. The database is pre-populated with a set of `Item` records (it's a limited set).

My context has mapped this nicely to the database and I'm doing a large data insertion of new records. There's another bit of code that is filling the objects with data. This is the actual import through EF:

```
public void ImportDemo(IEnumerable<Demo> demos)
{
    var context = this.UnitOfWork.MyApplicationContext;

    foreach (var demo in demos)
    {
        this.DataSet.Add(demo);
        context.Entry(demo).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    // NOTE: expecting an empty db.
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My DbModelBuilder has the following:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Demo>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
                .WithMany(p => p.Children);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .HasOptional(p => p.Parent)
                .WithMany(p => p.Children);
```

I can import the `Demo` entities successfully, and the child `Demo` entities, **but each of the child `Demo` entities is creating a new `Item` in the database** rather than just linking up to the existing `Item`. Parent `Demo` entities don't have `Item` records, they are null.

How do I make sure that the child `Demo` entities link to the existing `Item` records rather than creating new ones?

Comment: I don't think the code your are showing here has the problem, I think the problem will appear once you show the code that instantiates the Demo objects in the parameter for your import function.

Comment: Thanks to @ArturoMartinez' comment I was able to focus on the problem correctly and I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole structure is set up in a business layer and mapped ([AutoMapper](http://www.automapper.org/)) to the models in question.

The `Item` objects are in the `DbContext.IDbSet<Item>.Local` collection but the dummy `Items` in the model need to be reset with the `Item` objects in the local collection as follows.

```
public void ImportDemo(IEnumerable<Demo> demos)
{
   foreach (var demo in demos)
   {
       foreach (var child in demo.Children)
       {
           child.Item = 
               dbContext.Items.Local.First(p => p.Id == child.Item.Id)
       }

       dbContext.Set<Demo>.Add(demo);
   }

   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I tried using `Attach()` but it didn't behave how I expected it to from the MSDN documentation.